# Riemann Zeta function: Integral representation in terms of Gamma function, interchange integration and sum?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, gamma-function, riemann-zeta

It is well known, that the Zeta function has this integral formula for $\Re z>1$:

$\Gamma(z)\zeta(z)=\int _0^{\infty}\frac{t^{z-1}}{e^t-1} \ dt$

In the proof (attached in the link), we can interchange the integration and the sum:
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-z}\Gamma(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\big(\int _0^{\infty}t^{z-1}e^{-nt} \ dt \big)=\int _0^{\infty}\big(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} t^{z-1}e^{-nt}  \big) \ dt$.
Can anybody tell me why we can interchange the integration and the sum? How can we prove this? Which theorem justifies this? (Maybe Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem?)

[The proof from Garling book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8psLP.png)

Answer (score 1):

For $\Re(s) > 1$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}\Gamma(s) = \lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^N \int_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-nx}dx= \lim_{N\to \infty}\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\frac{1-e^{-Nx}}{e^x-1}dx$$

$$= \lim_{N\to \infty}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx+O(e^{-N^{1/2}}\int_{N^{-1/2}}^\infty \frac{|x^{s-1}|}{e^x-1}dx)+O(\int_0^{N^{-1/2}} \frac{|x^{s-1}|}{e^x-1}dx)$$
$$ = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx$$